# Doctrine2 - Get entity ID before flush

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity, flush, persist

Is there any way to get an entity ID before the persist/flush?
I mean:

```
$entity = new PointData();
$form   = $this->createForm(new PointDataType(), $entity);
```

If I try **$entity->getId()** at this point, it returns nothing.

I can get it working by:

```
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

(supposing **$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();**)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Read about [identifier generation strategies](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys) on Doctrine's documentation pages.

Comment: Thank you Crozin.
I had already read all that stuff. I´m not trying to get the next auto index. It would fail if 2 users called that action simultaneously.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to know the ID of an entity before it's been persisted to the database, then you obviously can't use generated identifiers.  You'll need to find some way to generate unique identifiers yourself (perhaps some kind of hash function can produce unique-enough values).

This is rarely a good idea, though, so you should be careful.

I would think very carefully about why I need to know the identifier before flush.  Doctrine is quite good at letting you build up a big object graph, and persist/flush it all at once.  It seems likely that you've got something ugly in your architecture that you're trying to work around.  It might be a good idea to review that before going down the application-generated-id route.

Comment: Maybe you could use UUID for this task, since they are practically unique (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and they can be generated in advance, from PHP for example. I don't like them much, but would be a good solution.

Comment: @JorgeeFG - Absolutely.  UUIDs are a great for this use-case.  In the years since I wrote this answer, I've started preferring UUIDs as identifiers for entities.  https://github.com/ramsey/uuid is a pretty solid library for generating them, and https://github.com/ramsey/uuid-doctrine provides a doctrine type implementation that works well.

Comment: In fact, Ocramius himself (the Doctrine ORM project leader) recommends generating our own UUIDs instead of relying on Doctrine for that… One of the reasons for that is that this way we can have valid entities from the moment they're instantiated, also we know which ID they will have before persisting them...

Answer (score 12):

You can use the @PostPersist annotation. A method annotated with it will be executed just before the flush ends and the entity Id is already available.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html

postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the postPersist event.

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** 
 * @ORM\Entity 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks 
 */
class PointData
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;

     ...

     /** 
      * @ORM\PostPersist 
      */
     public function onPostPersist()
     {
         // Put some simple logic here that required the auto-generated Id.

         $this->doSomething($this->id);
     }
    
     ...

}
```

Comment: It'd probably be better to use an [event listener](https://symfony.com/doc/master/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) if you're using Symfony but still +1

Comment: I prefer to annotate the entity so that logic is not hidden in another place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an auto generate ID to get a key like universally unique identifiers (UUID) or you can take the events of symfony:
 postFlush - The postFlush event occurs at the end of a flush operation.

Answer (score 0):

[Doctrine best practices](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/62) says,

> You should avoid auto-generated identifiers. because:
>
> - Your DB operations will block each other
> - You are denying bulk inserts
> - You cannot make multi-request transactions
> - Your object is invalid until saved
> - Your object does not work without the DB
>
> So you can use **UUIDS** instead

```
public function __construct() {
     $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();  
}
```

Also, Doctrine supports the [UUID](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types) generation strategy since version 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the ID before flushing, but, if you really need to persist the entity without saving to the database you can try using [Transactions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/transactions.html).

Try something like this:

```
$em->beginTransaction();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
$id = $entity->getId();
//do some stuff and save when ready
$em->commit();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = new PointData();

$em->persist($entity);

$entity->getId() <-- return <int>

$em->flush();
```

after persist you can get id

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's good to provide code snippet as solutions, but code-only answers are considered bad practice. Please elaborate what this snippet does and how it fixes the problem.